# React native - exposed method

Tags: android, react-native

I am implementing custom component for React Native using Android. I would like to implement an function that will be executable from React native. I have found out that there is an @ReactMethod annotation, but it is taken into consideration by React only when I use it in a class that extends:

> ReactContextBaseJavaModule

But my needs are different. I need to execute a function on my component. I was trying to expose function by @ReactNative annotation in my class that extends:

> ViewGroupManager

but this function is not visible for react at all. Is there any possibility to get access to the ViewGroupManager object from ReactContextBaseJavaModule object? If not than what is the most convenient way to expose function from native component to ReactNative?

here is my ReactContextBaseJavaModule implementation:

```
 public class VidyoModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public VidyoModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RNTVideoManager";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void showToast(){
        Toast.makeText(getCurrentActivity(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void connectToRoom(){

    }
}
```

I am able to execute both showToast and connectToRoom functions from react.

Here is an implementation of ViewGroupManager:

```
public class VidyoComponentManager extends ViewGroupManager<VidyoView> {
    private static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "RNTVideo";

    public VidyoComponentManager(){
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return COMPONENT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected VidyoView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new VidyoView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void connectToRoom(){

    }
}
```

My ReactPackage looks like this:

```
public class VidyoPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        VidyoModule module = new VidyoModule(reactContext);
        modules.add(module);
        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.<ViewManager>singletonList(
                new VidyoComponentManager()
        );
    }
}
```

and in this case function connectToRoom is not visible for ReactNative. What shouldI do here? Should I user commands?

```
public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return MapBuilder.<String, Integer>builder()
            .put("connectToRoom", 1)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found. To make functions from ViewManager(android side) visible to React Native we need to implement getCommandsMap, than iterate through commands and "registrate" them as available functions on React side

```
const commands = NativeModules.UIManager.RNTVideo.Commands;

Object.keys(commands).forEach(command => {
  NativeModules.RNTVideoManager[command] = (handle, ...rawArgs) => {
    const args = rawArgs.map(arg => {
      if (typeof arg === 'function') {
        callbackMap.set(nextCallbackId, arg);
        return nextCallbackId++;
      }
      return arg;
    });
    NativeModules.UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(handle, commands[command], args);
  };
});
```

If there is any better solution please tell me about it :)

Comment: I think you can call `UIManager.RNTVideo.Commands.connectToRoom` directly.